# How do I create history files with date automatically attached?

Tags: shell, command-history

E.g. at the end of the session for each day I want to create a history file with the date attached at the end.

So, say, history > history07162012.txt or something like that.

Comment: I would suggest using a standard timestamp instead of your US specific and unsortable one, i.e. `history20120716.txt`  by using `date +%Y%m%d`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming history files are hidden (beginning with `.`), I would do like:

```
ls -1 ~/.*history
```

With output:

```
/home/birei/.bash_history
/home/birei/.mysql_history
/home/birei/.ptksh_history
/home/birei/.sqlite_history
/home/birei/.xsh2_history
/home/birei/.xsh_history
```

Execute:

```
for hist_file in ~/.*history; do cp "$hist_file" "$hist_file$(date +%m%d%Y).txt"; done
```

And then:

```
ls -1 ~/.*history*
```

With following output:

```
/home/birei/.bash_history
/home/birei/.bash_history07172012.txt
/home/birei/.mysql_history
/home/birei/.mysql_history07172012.txt
/home/birei/.ptksh_history
/home/birei/.ptksh_history07172012.txt
/home/birei/.sqlite_history
/home/birei/.sqlite_history07172012.txt
/home/birei/.xsh2_history
/home/birei/.xsh2_history07172012.txt
/home/birei/.xsh_history
/home/birei/.xsh_history07172012.txt
```

I hope it can be useful for your question.